# How often should I create a new instance of a class?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm not a "die hard" coder and I need some advice.

I'm developing a website where users may search for a store or a brand.

I've created a class called **Search** and **Store**.

There are two ways search is executed: **"jQuery Live Search"** and **"normal search"**.

Live search is triggered for each character entered above 2 characters. So if you enter 5 characters, a search is performed 3 times. If the store you are looking for is in the dropdown list, you can click the store and the store page will be loaded.

The other search is when you click the search button after entering 3 or more characters.

Every time a search is performed, the following code is executed

```
$search = new Search();
$result = $search->search($_GET);
```

Each time a store page is loaded a `$store = new Store()` is executed.

**My question is this:**

Let's assume I get a very successful website and I have aroun 100 users per hour. Each user searches at least 3 times and looks at least 5 stores.

That means between 300 and 900 search objects are created every hour and 500 store objects.

Is it bad or good to create so many new objects?

I've read a bit about `Singleton`, but many advices against this.

How should I do this to achieve best performance? Any specific design pattern I should use?

Comment: Creating objects should be the *least* of the concerns. I don't use PHP, but both Java and C# can create *hundreds of thousands* of objects each second (actually well into the millions for most trivial objects); or consider a language like Python where *even integers are objects* (some are cached). Even throwing out two factors of ten and you're still very safe. So ... please. Design "well" and *run a performance analysis*.

Comment: @pst Very good point. So many sins have been commited in the name of performance. If your code is written well, refactored often, you will always have a good start doing performance tunining. You could do load tests to find bottlenecks.

Comment: @pst - Thanks. I'm just a front end developer and have never had to worry about these things. Nice to know that creating objects will not choke the server. I'll design as well as I can and do performace testing when the time comes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that creating the classes will become a bottleneck for your site. Look at an MVC Framework like Zend Framework, and examine how many instances of classes are generated for every call. The overhead of creating an instance of a class is almost nothing, the search will put heat on your db(assuming you are using a db like mysql).

I suggest using a timer for your jQuery Live search to do the search after the user stopped entering more characters. Like refreshing everytime the timer when a character has been entered and when the timer fires you can actually search.

I think one of the bigger problems will be your database. If you have many reading requests a good caching layer like [memcache](http://memcached.org/) may take a good heap of load from you DB.

Optimizing your db for searches should be a good measure to hold performance high. There are many tweaks and best practices to follow to get the most out of the db you are using.

As a comment of prodigitalson suggested diving into full text search with [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html#Apache%20Lucene) could even be more efficient than tuning the db.

If Lucene is bit overhead for you, you may want to look at the [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.lucene.intro.html) component, which does the same job and is written in php.

Comment: To add to this you might want to look at pulling the searching entirely out of the db by indexing the content thats in the db with Lucene or something similar. Even if this uses a db backend the records would still be disassociated from the primary site DB so you could move it to an entirely different database instance or server. You'll also probably get better search results...

Comment: I have no experience with chaching. I found this article, http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/oo-php5-adding-caching-to-data-access-layer/. I will see if I can implement this - unless you have a better idea?

Comment: @prodigitalson - that's a good point. I need to increse the speed on search. It's to slow right now.

Comment: @Steven Have a look at [this introduction to memcache](http://www.search-this.com/2007/07/24/an-introduction-to-memcached/), which shows a much easier approach than the link you have posted. Just to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. I will test memcache before I test the more advanced Lucene.

Answer (score 3):

Don't overcomplicate your design by guessing at performance bottlenecks. Number of objects created would rarely be an issue.

If you need to optimize at a later point, a memcached layer could help you.

Comment: I'm basically in agreement with Mads. Premature optimization is a developer sin. Don't develop yourself into a hole, be smart about it, but cross the shitload-of-users-bridge should you ever get to it.

Also, for clarity, you should be concerned with the amount of requests being generated, which sounds like it's happening when 2+ characters are typed via AJAX. Your 'Search' objects are created and destroyed with each request and in this case seems extremely negligible -- you're concerned with bandwidth and server load.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an high number of objects shouldn't be a performance problem in your application even if you have to pay a bit of attention to the dimensions of these objects.

Don't complicate too much your design, but i think that singleton pattern isn't a complication and it isn't difficult to implement.

So if the same object instance can be reused more times upon different search from the same user (or even by different users, if it is possible inside your application logic), then don't be afraid of using singleton. It saves your memory and preserves you from doing errors related of having multiple instance of objects that performs the same task, eventually sharing resources.